# How to create a 3D matrix with 3 columns and each column having 1000 rows

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code that I have:

```
positionMatrix = ([0]*1000, [0]*1000, [0]*1000)
```

Comment: Do you actually want an array, or do you want a list of lists, or do you want a tuple of lists, or ... ? If you really want a matrix, use numpy. Also, 1000 x 3 is not a 3D matrix.

Comment: Isn't 3 x 1000 a matrix. And I am using Python 3. I don't believe numpy is compatible with Python 3.

Comment: @Seth, and I really want a multi dimensional array. With 3 columns, each column having 1000 rows

Comment: @kachilous: numpy works with Python 3 since some time last year.

Comment: @kachilous: Your question title says "3D".

Comment: @kachilous: 3 dimensions and 3 columns are completely different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still not really clear what you want.

If you want multidimensional array you can use lists:

```
>>> matrix = [[None]*10 for x in range(3)]#replace 10 with 1000 or what ever
>>> matrix
[[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
>>>
```

Also I would recommend the use of `None` rather that `0`.

You can acces the matrix like this:

```
>>> matrix[1][3] = 55
>>> matrix
[[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, 55, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
```

Is this what you were aiming for?

For a better visual representation you could do something like:

```
>>> for x in matrix:
...     print(x, "\n")
... 
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None] 

[None, None, None, 55, None, None, None, None, None, None] 

[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

<strike>You could also go with:</strike>

```
>>> matrix = [[None]*10 for x in xrange(3)]
```

Read about it [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange).

Since you are using python 3x. you should use `range()`. Se more [here](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/whatsnew/3.0.html?highlight=xrange#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists).

Oh and by the way there is nothing particularly wrong with what you are doing, you are using a tuple instead of a list, these are not mutable, but the nested lists inside are, so you can modify it:

```
>>> positionMatrix = ([0]*10, [0]*10, [0]*10)
>>> positionMatrix
([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> positionMatrix[0][4] = 99
>>> positionMatrix
([0, 0, 0, 0, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Just don't do this:

```
>>> positionMatrix = [[0]*10]*3
>>> positionMatrix[0][4] = 99
>>> positionMatrix
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>>
```

It refers to the same object in memory.

Just in case, you can use this:

```
>>> positionMatrix = [[0]*10, [0]*10, [0]*10]
>>> positionMatrix
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> positionMatrix[0][4] = 99
>>> positionMatrix
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Since you would be creating 3 different objects.

Comment: This gives me a syntax error: for x in matrix:
     print x, "\n"

Comment: @kachilous: ohh sorry, forgot you were using python 3.x try `print(x, "\n")`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. Also, what is the difference between matrix = [[None]*10 for x in xrange(3)] and matrix = [[None]*10 for x in range(3)]

Comment: @kachilous: My bad again. If you are using python 3.x you should use `range()` see this: http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/whatsnew/3.0.html?highlight=xrange#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists

Comment: So I should always use the second: matrix = [[None]*10 for x in range(3)]?

Comment: @kachilous: No problem, glad it helped! For the next time just try to be a little more specific with your question, and you'll get better answers sooner and give more background to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If performance isn't critical, you can use dictionaries as multidimensional arrays in Python.

```
positionMatrix = {}
positionMatrix[ row, col ] = foo
```

To initialize it to 3 x 1000 zeros:

```
for col in range( 3 ):
    for row in range( 1000 ):
        positionMatrix[ row, col ] = 0.0
```

Or just

```
from collections import defaultdict
positionMatrix = defaultdict(float)
```

Which initializes each element to 0 when it's first accessed.

If you're after a high performance numeric matrix, check out `numpy`.

EDIT: Updated for 3 columns by 1000 rows rather than a 3D matrix.

Comment: He is using python 3.x I think numpy isn't yet available for it.

Comment: Wikipedia says numpy 1.5+ supports Python 3.

Comment: [Thats true!](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files//NumPy/1.5.0/NOTES.txt/view) sorry about that! My mistake!!

Answer (score -1):

`positionMatrix = [[[0 for x in range(1000)] for x in range(1000)] for x in range(1000)]`

This is the same as int positionMatrix[1000][1000][1000] in C/C++.